# Quote-related error when trying to run a shell script via AppleScript inside of Swift code

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, applescript

I'm writing an AppleScript that I'm going to run in a macOS app. This script works fine in Script Editor but when I bring it into Xcode and try to run it, encoding a URL fails with an error about quotation marks.

I'd love any tips to get this to run successfully via Swift and Xcode rather than just Script Editor. Thanks!

My code:

```
        var source = """
        on encode(str)
            do shell script "php -r 'echo urlencode(\"" & str & "\");'"
        end encode

        set f to encode("https://twitter.com")
        f
        """
        let script = NSAppleScript(source: source)!
        var error: NSDictionary? = nil
        let result = script.executeAndReturnError(&error)

        print(result.stringValue)
        print(error)
```

Error prints out:

```
Optional({
    NSAppleScriptErrorBriefMessage = "Expected end of line but found \U201c\"\U201d.";
    NSAppleScriptErrorMessage = "Expected end of line but found \U201c\"\U201d.";
    NSAppleScriptErrorNumber = "-2741";
    NSAppleScriptErrorRange = "NSRange: {60, 1}";
})
```

Comment: What in the world…?! Is there a particular reason you *have* to call AppleScript to call Bash to call PHP to URL-encode a string, as opposed to just using `NSString.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters:…)` which would be the non-insane way to do it? And even if you do need to call PHP for some opaque purpose, you don’t need the rest of that nonsense; just use [Swift’s `Process`](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/system/how-to-run-an-external-program-using-process) to run `/usr/bin/php` directly.

Comment: I'm pretty new to AppleScript and haven't really used Foundation as part of my scripts, which is what you're suggesting but yeah, this is a pretty weird way to do it, kluged together from SO answers from years past. Thanks for the feedback

Comment: SO is the beginning of wisdom, not the end. If you’re trying to perform a common task and it’s proving difficult, most likely it’s because you’re doing it the worst way possible, having completely missed all the safer, simpler, easier, correct solutions that already exist. Half the challenge in becoming a competent coder is learning to recognize when you’re digging yourself into a big dumb hole and say: “This cannot be right; there **must** be an easier way.” In this case, the right question to ask is “How do I *URL-encode a string in Swift*?”, from which finding the right answer is easy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quoting strings in shell scripts can be annoying.

Try this, `quoted form of` looks for the best combination

```
do shell script "php -r " & quoted form of ("echo urlencode(" & quote & str & quote & ");")
```

By the way `NSRange: {60, 1}` tells you where the error occurs (the 61st character in the string)